# How to obtain an result from comparing an input word with elements from an String array Java

Tags: java

So what I'm trying to achieve is that when I write a word like "Meat" at the request of the input, the method will check the relations, and will run the appropriate result for the word "Meat", like if is "Meat" is the input "woof" should be printed.But on execution nothing happens .I have to tell that I'm new to Java and programming. Thank you for patience!

```
 package animals;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Animal {

    public int hungerLvl = 0;   
    public String food;
    public String[] foodTypes = {"Meat" , "Grass", "Water"};
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void  eatFood(){

       System.out.println("Enter food: ");
       food = in.nextLine();    
       if(food == foodTypes[0].toString()){
          System.out.println("woof");
          hungerLvl++;
          System.out.println("Hunger lvl incresead to " + hungerLvl);
       } else {
           if (food == foodTypes[1].toString()){
               System.out.println("Animal is eating grass");
               hungerLvl++;
           }
           if (food == foodTypes[2].toString()){
               System.out.println("Animal is drinking water");
               hungerLvl++;
           }           
       }  
    }
    //ignore this method :)
    public int maxLvl(){
       if(hungerLvl == 5){
           System.out.println("No more food, going to take a nap!");
           hungerLvl = hungerLvl - 5;
       }
       return 0;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args){
        Animal animal = new Animal();

     animal.eatFood();
     }
     }
```

Comment: this won't work: `food == foodTypes[1].toString()` you want to use String.equals

Comment: Do you have a specific question or problem?

Comment: This is a bit vague/broad. Currently this reads more like "debug my code for me" while it *should* read more like "here's a specific problem with the relevant code"

Comment: Well the ideea is that when I write the input as "Meat" or "Grass" , I want the program to output the result of the matched word like if  i write as Input : Meat then as output will be "Woof" word from the method,but instead when I'm typing and pressing enter to run nothing returns, I repeat I'm a newbie, and not looking for new entire code to resolve the problem, but tips, thank you!

Comment: well do you really need those `if` statements inside the `else` .You could straight away use `else if()` staements [examples](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-if-else)  or a `for` loop with `if` statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use str.equals or str.match

```
   public void  eatFood(){
   System.out.println("Enter food: ");
   food = in.nextLine();    
   if(food.matches(foodTypes[0])){
      System.out.println("woof");
      hungerLvl++;
      System.out.println("Hunger lvl incresead to " + hungerLvl);
   } else {
       if (food.matches(foodTypes[1])){
           System.out.println("Animal is eating grass");
           hungerLvl++;
       }
       if (food.matches(foodTypes[2])){
           System.out.println("Animal is drinking water");
           hungerLvl++;
       }           
   }  
}
```